# UI Doesn't Hold Checkbox Value Of Selected Item In Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, matblazor

I have a MatBlazor table that has a datasource (Items) and check boxes associated with each row in the table. If I use @bind-Value I have no issues and all works as designed. BUT I am adding validation to a button that depends on whether any items in the list are "Checked" in order to enable it.

So, I moved to using the ValueChanged attribute which is an EventCallback and having no luck updating the UI with the selected value.

I have tried calling StateHasChanged() and even InvokeAsync(), yet the UI does not update.

```
  <MatTable Items="@Projects" class="mat-elevation-z5 create-build-list" PageSize="50" ShowPaging="false" FilterByColumnName="ProjectName" Striped="true">
                        <MatTableHeader>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Key</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Include</th>
                        </MatTableHeader>
                        <MatTableRow>
                            <td>@context.ProjectName</td>
                            <td>@context.Key</td>
                            <td>@context.ProjectType</td>
                            <td><MatCheckbox Label="Add To Build" ValueChanged="@((bool val) => CheckBoxValue(val, context))" ValueExpression="@(() => context.IsChecked)"></MatCheckbox></td>
                        </MatTableRow>
                    </MatTable>
```

Here is the Method

```
   void CheckBoxValue(bool e, MyProjectKey key)
{
    foreach(var p in Projects)
    {
        if(p.Key == key.Key)
        {
            p.IsChecked = true;
        }
    };
//-- I'll do more stuff here.
}
```

Is there something I'm missing as it calls the function but does not update the UI.

Comment: Did you mean to pass context.Key to the method? You seem to be passing the whole context/Project

Comment: if I change the type to string and just pass the "Key" without the object I get the same result. The model in the @code{} block shows it updates, but the UI doesn't hold the Selection. I've also tried adding the StateHasChanged() component.Base method to notify for re-render and still the view does not hold the change. It's odd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the intended behaviour of Blazor/MatBlazor, but I faced the same problem and the only solution I found was to first of all use 'Value' instead of 'ValueExpression' as this was not setting the UI properly for me, then set the field value in the 'context' directly in the 'ValueChanged' callback and this caused the UI to update to the value set in the 'context'.

So if you change your Razor code to this:-

```
<MatTable Items="@Projects" class="mat-elevation-z5 create-build-list" PageSize="50" ShowPaging="false" FilterByColumnName="ProjectName" Striped="true">
<MatTableHeader>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Include</th>
</MatTableHeader>
<MatTableRow>
    <td>@context.ProjectName</td>
    <td>@context.Key</td>
    <td>@context.ProjectType</td>
    <td><MatCheckbox Label="Add To Build" Value="@context.IsChecked" ValueChanged="@((bool val) => CheckBoxValue(val, context))"></MatCheckbox></td>
</MatTableRow>
```

Then change the callback code to this:-

```
void CheckBoxValue(bool val, MyProjectKey context)
{
    // This line updates the UI
    context.IsChecked = val;
    
    foreach (var p in Projects)
    {
        if (p.Key == context.Key)
        {
            p.IsChecked = true;
        }
    };
    
    // I'll do more stuff here.
}
```

Hopefully that should work...

One other issue I faced with this was to do with Entity Framework, so you may or may not hit the same problem as me there too depending on what else you are doing in the callback.

For better or worse, I was calling a database insert/update in my ValueChanged callback. The problem was though that the all the models in table list were being 'tracked' by Entity Framework and updating the Blazor 'context' (not the DbContext) was also modifying entities that were tracked!

However, since it was just a list of models for displaying the table rows/columns I added 'AsNoTracking' to my DbContext call. If I didn't do this, I got errors about EF trying to saving the values (the DbSet in question was just linked to a view in the database which obviously is read only) the next time I called 'SaveChanges' anywhere!! ;-)

**Edit**

Sorry, forgot to mention that this was on a Blazor server project, so the EF tracking probably won't affect you if you're using Blazor client side project...